# Stop a M2M relationship being saved in django

Tags: django

I have an AdminModel that allows users to save with any of the fields left empty. However, I don't want them to be able to save when all fields are empty. I've implemented this using the following:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if form.has_changed():
        obj.save()
    else:
        pass
```

However, the Model has a M2M relationship with another Model, so I get the following error when I hit save:

```
instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

What do I need to add to this method to stop it trying to create the M2M relationship?

**Edit:**

I've added hacky workaround, but I'd be interested in knowing if there's a better way of doing it. The workaround was to change the `else` so it changes the ModelAdmin's field attribute so that it doesn't contain the field for the M2M relationship - this prevents it from trying to make the relationship. This is not only hacky, but also only works after it's failed to save the model once and thrown an error...

Comment: if it fails it's not a solution. Also, that solution is not thread safe.

Comment: I know, I was just trying to work out if there was a way to do what I wanted. I'm new to django so I was just trying things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - `save_m2m` is called after `save_model`. The docs specifically say this hook is [not for veto purposes.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

> ModelAdmin.save_model() and ModelAdmin.delete_model() must save/delete
>   the object, they are not for veto purposes, rather they allow you to
>   perform extra operations.

What you need is form validation to prevent `save_model` from triggering. Somehow, you need to detect when all fields are left blank.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean(self):
        if not any(self.cleaned_data.values()):
            raise forms.ValidationError("All fields cannot be blank!")
        return self.cleaned_data

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

Comment: I didn't know about `any()`. Very useful.

Comment: @pastylegs `any` and `all`! PS: saw you on WP!

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to do the validation at the form level instead of the admin level. To do this, create a custom `Form` class to be used by your `ModelAdmin`. So create a `forms.py`:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
from django import forms

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pass

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean(self):
        empty = True
        for field_name, field_data in self.cleaned_data.iteritems():
            if field_data:
                empty = False
        if empty:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The form cannot be empty")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

and allow your admin to use this form. In `admin.py`:

```
from myapp.forms import MyModelForm
from django.contrib import admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    form = MyModelForm
```

Comment: I had to change for `field_data in self.cleaned_data` to `for field_name, field_data in self.cleaned_data.iteritems()` to get it to work, but this does exactly what I wanted and was very clearly explained. Thanks!

Comment: and btw, Yuji's solution to checking the fields for emptiness is probably more concise

Comment: you're right - I'll do it that way instead. Everybody gets rep for being helpful :)